# Documentation for BTRFS shorthand?

Tags: btrfs, documentation

I came across [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46384/38061) where the answerer wrote

```
btrfs sub snap -r fs snapshot
```

among other things, where `subvolume` and `snapshot` were substituted for `sub` and `snap`. Sure enough, those commands work, but I can't find any documentation for them. Is there a place where the available shorthand `btrfs` commands are documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for this is in the `man` page for `btrfs`:

> It is possible to abbreviate the commands unless the commands are ambiguous. For example: it is possible to run `btrfs sub snaps` instead of `btrfs subvolume snapshot`. But `btrfs file s` is not allowed, because `file s` may be interpreted both as `filesystem show` and as `filesystem sync`. If a command is terminated by `--help`, the detailed help is showed. If the passed command matches more commands, detailed help of all the matched commands is showed. For example `btrfs dev --help` shows the help of all `device*` commands.